# Binning data frame using a column and calculating the median

Tags: r

I have a file with genes along a chromosome, and their expression

```
  Gene_id        rpkm   chr    start     stop
AT1G01010     4.18954  Chr1     3631     5899
AT1G01020    10.22902  Chr1     5928     8737
AT1G01030     1.99064  Chr1    11649    13714
.
.
AT1G80980     5.67423  Chr1 30422058 30424087
AT1G80990     79.5678  Chr1 30424421 30425192
```

I want to, using the start column, divide the file up in 20,000 windows.
So to first get the median of genes that fall into the window from 0-20,000 and then from 20,000 to 40,000 and so on.

I would like a file in the end that looks like this

```
 chr  start   stop  median   
Chr1      0  20000       x
Chr1  20000  40000       y
```

I have tried writing a function

```
exp <- read.table(file='cegs_chr1ath_pos.txt', header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

slide_function <- function(data, window, step){
  #get how many genes looking at along chromosome
  total <- length(data)
  #use seq() to get a sequence of expression values from 0 to total
  points <- seq(from=0, to=30424421, by = step)
  result <- vector(length = length(points))
  for(i in 1:length(points)){
    result[i] <- median(data[points[i]:(points[i] + window - 1)],)
  }
  return(result)
}

slide_function(exp$start,20000,200)
```

However I am not sure how to get the function to calculate the median of the rpkm value for that window, or how to get it to produce the result file I am hoping for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with genomics, you should consider using `dplyr` to simplify your handling of big dataframes. Here's a solution using it.

First, the data you provided:

```
exp <- read.table(text="Gene_id        rpkm   chr    start     stop
AT1G01010     4.18954  Chr1     3631     5899
AT1G01020    10.22902  Chr1     5928     8737
AT1G01030     1.99064  Chr1    11649    13714
AT1G80980     5.67423  Chr1 30422058 30424087
AT1G80990     79.5678  Chr1 30424421 30425192", header=T, as.is=T)
```

Now what we do is create a column which is the `start` value transformed into the corresponding window, using the integer division `%/%`. Then, we group the rows by window, and take the median of rpkm for each group, using `summarise()`. Finally, we recreate the `start` and `stop` columns according to `window` and `step` using `mutate()` and remove the `window` column using `select()`:

```
step = 20000

library(dplyr)
newexp <- exp %>% 
  mutate(window = .$start %/% step) %>% 
  group_by(window) %>% summarise(rpkm_median = median(rpkm)) %>%
  mutate(start = window*step, stop=(window+1)*step) %>%
  select(-window)
```

Resulting in:

```
  rpkm_median    start     stop
1     4.18954        0    20000
2    42.62101 30420000 30440000
```

Comment: sorry to ask this so late, but do you know the best way to plot this in R. I have tried using plot() followed by lines(), but I cannot get the x axis to be the different bins.

Comment: How do you want the plot? `start` on x and `rpkm` on y? You can plot directly with lines using `plot(newexp$start, newexp$rpkm_median, type="l")`